# Objects in entity associations in JPA

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, associations

I have an entity:

```
    package com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.domain;

    import javax.persistence.*;

    /**
     * Created by Игорь on 03.04.2016.
     */

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "cases")
    public class Case {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        private String caseNumber;

        private String dataI;

        private String dataII;

        private String dataIII;

        private long judgeID;

        private long lawyerID;

        private long clientID;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        private Judge judge;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        private Lawyer lawyer;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        private Client client;

        @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
        private CaseStatus statusI;

        @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
        private CaseStatus statusII;

        @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
        private CaseStatus statusIII;

        private String document;

        // getters and setters
    }
```

As u can see there are three objects: **Judge, Lawyer and Client** which are associated with my entity. When I am fetching the entity I getting error: NullPointerException. Therefore I am forced to instantiate that objects in **CaseServiceImpl.java**  to avoid exception:

```
public Case findById(long id) {
    Case c = entityManager.find(Case.class, id);
    c.setJudge(new JudgeServiceImpl().findById(c.getJudgeID()));
    c.setClient(new ClientServiceImpl().findById(c.getClientID()));
    c.setLawyer(new LawyerServiceImpl().findById(c.getLawyerID()));
    return c;
}
```

Is it a right way to do so?
My JSP page code:

```
<%@ page import="com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.domain.Case" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<fmt:requestEncoding value="UTF-8"/>

<%-- HEADER --%>

<c:import url="/common/header.jsp">
    <c:param name="title" value="Cases"/>
    <c:param name="a" value="Дела"/>
</c:import>

<%-- BODY --%>

<div class="table-header">
    <div class="first-header-element">№</div>
    <div class="header-element">Номер дела</div>
    <div class="header-element">Представитель</div>
    <div class="header-element">Клиент</div>
    <div class="last-header-element"></div>
</div>

<br>

<%List<Case> cases = (List<Case>) request.getAttribute("cases");
  int count = 0;
  for (Case c : cases) {%>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <label>
        <textarea class="first-element" readonly><%= ++count%></textarea>
    </label>
    <label>
        <textarea class="element" readonly><%= c.getCaseNumber()%></textarea>
    </label>
    <label>
        <textarea class="element" readonly><%= c.getLawyer().getLawyerName()%></textarea>
    </label>
    <label>
        <textarea class="element" readonly><%= c.getClient().getClientName()%></textarea>
    </label>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showSingleCase?caseID=<%=c.getId()%>"><label>
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Детальней" style="width: 10%">
    </label></a>
</div>
<%}%>

<%-- FOOTER --%>

<c:import url="/common/footer.jsp">
</c:import>
```

Error occuring at a string:

```
<textarea class="element" readonly><%= c.getLawyer().getLawyerName()%></textarea>
```

Comment: Why would you store "judgeID", "lawyerID", "clientID" in fields when you have the actual objects already present?!

Comment: Because I am using NamedQueries wich requires object id-s (not entire object...). Table cases contain few foreign keys. And to do some sql selection (concrete cases) i need to use foreign keys. Can I use object fields in named queries?

Comment: Of course you can use fields in JPQL and NamedQueries are just JPQL!

Comment: @NeilStockton OK, but I still have an error, because I must to instantiate objects inside case entity (when I am fetching an entity in JSP page)!

Comment: What persistence provider? If you are accessing in JSP then it is possible associations are not initialized due to lazy loading. So providers may throw a lazy loading exception in such case. Others (OpenJPA) may simple return null. What is returned by calling c.getJudge() in your service

Comment: I'm using hibernate. So what i should to do?

Comment: If in your service you call **Case c = entityManager.find(Case.class, id);c.getJudge()** what is returned.

Comment: I am getting org.apache.jasper.JasperException: **An exception occurred processing JSP page /show/all/cases.jsp at line 49** in JPS page. but in System.out.println(c.getJudgeName); before errored line I get correct data...in service I have correct data

Comment: Sounds like a JSP issue then. Update your question with the relevant JSP code?

Answer (score -2):

I see u are missing the implement `serialization` in  `entity class`, or have already created the interface for the `entity` class. smth like `CaseRepository` `interface` where u can declare the method '`findById`' because i suppose the default method of `jpa` to get by id is '`getById`', so that might be a custom method u r trying to create.